# Alexa keeps responding with 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response'

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

When i type open , the response from the Alexa is perfectly normal but for any other question i ask which associates with other intents i created, Alexa keeps responding with 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response'. I have used the Alexa Hosted endpoints in python too.

I have researched different 'solutions' including turning Display Interface on and I've looked through my code several times, but no use.

My Skill ID: amzn1.ask.skill.4176db22-7239-413e-a56e-afeafda524b8